# How to show tooltip on a Google Pie Chart on legend hover?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, legend, mousehover, legend-properties

I want to show the tooltip of the slices on the mouse hover in the legend.
By default it shows the tooltip only when the mouse is over a slice of the pie.

Currently the nearest thing I have is to show the tooltip when I click on the legend, with:

```
tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }
```

as option when I draw the chart.

I tried to find something into the reference with no result.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ohavpo17/2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are close. Keep `tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }` and add an event listener to `onmouseover` :

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function(entry) {
   chart.setSelection([{row: entry.row}]);
});
```

This will show the tooltip when the mouse hover the legend. As the [**docs**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Events) says about `onmouseover`:

> Fired when the user mouses over a visual entity. Passes back the row
>   and column indices of the corresponding data table element. A slice or
>   legend entry correlates to a row in the data table (column index is
>   null).

So the above code simply simulates a selection for the row corresponding to the legend being hovered. I would also add an `onmouseout` listener, so a tooltip not hangs when the mouse leaves the chart :

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', function(entry) {
   chart.setSelection([]);
});
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/a095qq8e/**